# Cocos2d 2.0 - cannot find spriteFrame?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am developing for iPad with Cocos2D 2.0.

I have these lines:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"atlas.plist"];
CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"atlas.png"];
[self addChild:batchNode];

CCSprite *mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFrameName:@"white.png"];
```

it fails miserably with this error:

**Cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Frame 'white.png' not found
*** Assertion failure in -[CCSprite initWithSpriteFrame:], /Users/myUser/Documents/MyApp/MyApp/libs/cocos2d/CCSprite.m:212**

I have generated the plist using TexturePacker. TexturePacker created 4 files: atlas-ipadhd.plis, atlas-ipadhd.png, atlas.plist and atlas.png.

**white-ipadhd.png is a 2x2 white picture. white.png is a 1x1 white picture.**

This is the content of atlas-ipadhd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>frames</key>
        <dict>
            <key>white-ipadhd.png</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{162,2},{2,2}}</string>
                <key>offset</key>
                <string>{0,0}</string>
                <key>rotated</key>
                <false/>
                <key>sourceColorRect</key>
                <string>{{0,0},{2,2}}</string>
                <key>sourceSize</key>
                <string>{2,2}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>bgNormal-ipadhd.png</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{2,2},{348,78}}</string>
                <key>offset</key>
                <string>{0,0}</string>
                <key>rotated</key>
                <true/>
                <key>sourceColorRect</key>
                <string>{{0,0},{348,78}}</string>
                <key>sourceSize</key>
                <string>{348,78}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>bgPressed-ipadhd.png</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{82,2},{348,78}}</string>
                <key>offset</key>
                <string>{0,0}</string>
                <key>rotated</key>
                <true/>
                <key>sourceColorRect</key>
                <string>{{0,0},{348,78}}</string>
                <key>sourceSize</key>
                <string>{348,78}</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>format</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>realTextureFileName</key>
            <string>atlas-ipadhd.png</string>
            <key>size</key>
            <string>{256,512}</string>
            <key>smartupdate</key>
            <string>$TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:f709325b7d140d102cd10dd90ef475b0$</string>
            <key>textureFileName</key>
            <string>atlas-ipadhd.png</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

**This is atlas.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>frames</key>
        <dict>
            <key>white.png</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{84,2},{1,1}}</string>
                <key>offset</key>
                <string>{0,0}</string>
                <key>rotated</key>
                <false/>
                <key>sourceColorRect</key>
                <string>{{0,0},{1,1}}</string>
                <key>sourceSize</key>
                <string>{1,1}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>bgNormal.png</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{2,2},{174,39}}</string>
                <key>offset</key>
                <string>{0,0}</string>
                <key>rotated</key>
                <true/>
                <key>sourceColorRect</key>
                <string>{{0,0},{174,39}}</string>
                <key>sourceSize</key>
                <string>{174,39}</string>
            </dict>
            <key>bgPressed.png</key>
            <dict>
                <key>frame</key>
                <string>{{43,2},{174,39}}</string>
                <key>offset</key>
                <string>{0,0}</string>
                <key>rotated</key>
                <true/>
                <key>sourceColorRect</key>
                <string>{{0,0},{174,39}}</string>
                <key>sourceSize</key>
                <string>{174,39}</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>format</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>realTextureFileName</key>
            <string>atlas.png</string>
            <key>size</key>
            <string>{128,256}</string>
            <key>smartupdate</key>
            <string>$TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:c3c8dd4637d116b049a6b55c8ad175d0$</string>
            <key>textureFileName</key>
            <string>atlas.png</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

this is atlas-ipadhd.png and atlas.png

[image]
[image]

after looking at this for hours, I cannot able to find anything wrong with these files... but it still crashes catastrophically.

any clues? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sprite frame name should be white.png in atlas-ipadhd.plist.

straight from the horses' mouth:

```
+(id)spriteWithSpriteFrameName:(NSString*)spriteFrameName
{
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:spriteFrameName];

    NSAssert1(frame!=nil, @"Invalid spriteFrameName: %@", spriteFrameName);
    return [self spriteWithSpriteFrame:frame];
}
```

There is no attempt to correct the frame name with device specific keys. This way your code can remain completely device agnostic, you just have to provide the resources (textures and plists) with the appropriate device specific file names.

Comment: why is that? shouldn't each plist refer to their correspondent files? why should the ipadhd plist refer to the non-hd file?

Comment: I guess it is a design decision on the part of coco's programmers.

Comment: why coco pick such ugly xml schema anyway?